# SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bitbucket, capistrano3

`$ bundle exec cap production deploy`

> (Backtrace restricted to imported tasks) cap aborted! 
>   
>   SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: 
>   
>  
>   Exception while executing as　Psara@sakura: git exit status: 128 git stdout: Nothing written git
>   stderr: Permission denied (publickey).
>   
>  
>   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
>
> SSHKit::Command::Failed: 
>   
>  
>   git exit status: 128 
>   
>   git stdout:Nothing written 
>   
>   git stderr: Permission denied (publickey). 
>   
>  
>   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
>   
>   Tasks: TOP => git:check (See full trace by running task with --trace)
>   The deploy has failed with an error: 
>   
>  
>   Exception while executing as Psara@sakura: 
>   
>  
>   git exit status: 128 git stdout: Nothing written 
>   
>  
>   git stderr: Permission denied (publickey).
>   
>   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

*

> **deploy.rb**
>
> set :application, 'Psara'
>    set :repo_url, 'git@bitbucket.org:CBLaughter/psara.git'
>    set :deploy_to, '/home/Psara/Psara'
>    set :default_run_options, :pty => true
>
> namespace :deploy do
>
> after :restart, :clear_cache do
>       on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
>         # Here we can do anything such as:
>         # within release_path do
>         #   execute :rake, 'cache:clear'
>         # end
>       end   end
>
> end
>
> set :ssh_options, { forward_agent: true, paranoid: true, keys:
>   "~/.ssh/id_rsa" }

*

> **production.rb**
>
> set :stage, :staging 
>   
>   set :rails_env, :production
>
> role :app, %w{sakura} 
>   
>   role :web, %w{sakura} 
>   
>   role :db, %w{sakura}
>
> server 'sakura', user: 'Psara', roles: %w{web app}, my_property: >:my_value
>
> set :ssh_options, { 
>   
>    keys: %w(~/.ssh/id_rsa), 
>   
>    forward_agent: false, }

**I would be glad, if you could teach me what I can do to solve this problem.**

**I have already added a public key on the bitbucket, but it doesn't work.**

*

**SSH agent forwarding report**

> ---
>
> 1. [success] `repo_url` setting ok
> 2. [success] ssh private key file exists
> 3. [success] `ssh-agent` process seems to be running locally
> 4. [success] `ssh-agent` process recognized by `ssh-add` command
> 5. [success] ssh private keys added to `ssh-agent`
> 6. [success] application repository accessible from local machine
> 7. [success] all hosts using passwordless login
> 8. [success] `forward_agent` ok for all hosts
> 9. [success] ssh agent successfully forwarded to remote hosts
> 10. [success] application repository accessible from remote hosts
>
> ---
>
> It seems SSH agent forwarding is set up correctly! You can continue
>   with the deployment process.
>
> **It succeeded in all tests, but still makes same error.**

Comment: Please edit your question to use code blocks so we can read it. Also clearly define what your error is.

Comment: @Shion Yamaguchi: How you solved your issue as I also Stuck!!! and  on same page as you were ?

Answer (score 60):

Make sure that you have ssh-agent running on your machine, because you're using ssh forwarding, your local keys should be able to access and clone your repo from bitbucket. You can run agent it with:

```
eval `ssh-agent`
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

More info about ssh-forwarding you can [find here](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/ssh-agent-forwarding.html).

Other thing you should check manually is that you can ssh to your server (your public key should be added to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on server), and of course that you can clone your repo locally (that probably you're able to do).

Update:

Now i have realised that you turn forwarding for production, in that case you should make sure that key-pair that's on your server (you must have it, because forwarding is turned off), are able to clone repo from bitbucket, you can try cloning on server by hand too.

Comment: Hey Rastasheep Even Im facing the same issue ..I gone through But did not able to sort out.

Comment: @rastasheep I have a similar issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36900222/ssh-agent-forwarding-with-capistrano-3-not-working-when-deploying-rails-app.  Does Capistrano log into the production server and then try to pull code from the repository to the production server? If that's what it does, is there a way to make Capistrano push code from the repository to the production server?

Comment: @massaskillz yeah, Capistrano just logs into your machine via SSH and there executes commands which are generated by it's DSL. You can create custom Capistrano tasks to do whatever you want. Unfortunately i think that is not possible to "push" from repository, it's possible to copy (via scp command) code from host machine to your server.

Answer (score 3):

As the backtrace says, this is likely related to ssh public keys. I would recommend troubleshooting the problem with [capistrano-ssh-doctor](https://github.com/capistrano-plugins/capistrano-ssh-doctor). You will get a report precisely saying what went wrong in the setup.

Disclaimer, I'm the author of `capistrano-ssh-doctor` plugin.