# Capistrano and Rails deployment, unable to access bitbucket repo from ubuntu server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ubuntu, ssh, capistrano3

I have an Ubuntu server which can successfully deploy a Rails project to. I have created a new project, and would like to deploy this to the same server. But i am having a problem with accessing the bitbucket repo the code is stored on during the Capistrano deployment.

```
DEBUG [60fbbd0f] Command: /usr/bin/env chmod +x /tmp/<project_name>/git-ssh.sh
INFO [60fbbd0f] Finished in 0.098 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [b7870f98] Running /usr/bin/env git ls-remote --heads git@bitbucket.org:rmac/<project_name>.git as www-data@88.xxx.xxx.xxx
DEBUG [b7870f98] Command: ( GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/<project_name>/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git ls-remote --heads git@bitbucket.org:rmac/<project_name>.git )
DEBUG [b7870f98]    conq: repository does not exist.
DEBUG [b7870f98]    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
DEBUG [b7870f98]    
DEBUG [b7870f98]    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
DEBUG [b7870f98]    and the repository exists.
```

I have tried this

[SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28375506/sshkitrunnerexecuteerror)

and other answers but to no avail. I have checked my server processes and ssh agent is running. I find it difficult to understand seeing as my other project deploys to the server no problems. I am using the same machine, the same deployment keys, the same bitbucket account.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/capistrano-plugins/capistrano-ssh-doctor ?

Comment: I had noticed this but seeing as it is two years old, I assume it wont have much to offer.

Comment: It's still pretty useful. At least, I'd suggest trying it before I tried to walk you through debugging this.

Comment: ok thanks man will give it a whirl now and report back

Comment: @will_in_wi yeah it hasn't told me anything new. the only thing I know for sure now is that ssh kit is running for sure. rest is the same as before. It trips on this  ssh:remote:repo_access

Comment: Are you depending on ssh-agent forwarding or deploy keys? If the latter, confirm that the key is added to the project. If the former, try to log into the server manually using ssh -A and git clone the project.

Comment: @will_in_wi ok so i am working with the former. and tried to clone the repo and received this... no such identity: /home/sites/.ssh/bitbucket_rsa: No such file or directory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112783/discussion-between-will-in-wi-and-rico-mac).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Answer figured out in chat)

Since ssh-agent is being used, use `ssh -A destination_server` and `git clone` to confirm that ssh-agent is working.

Since another project is deploying, confirm that the Bitbucket repo URL is correct. (this ended up being the answer)